# Angularjs: ng-repeat with clone feature

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects and I can clone a "row" (object) to populate the array. It works but when I modify any of value, all objects of the array is updated.

**TL;DR**: The cloned row must have independent values

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="comment in comments track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-model="comment.text">

        <button type="button" ng-click="cloneRow(comment)">Clone this row</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.comments = [
    { text: 'test' }
];

$scope.cloneRow = function(comment){
    $scope.comments.push(comment);
};
```

Current case:

1. Click on "Clone this row"
2. Type anything in the cloned input
3. The value of first input **has changed**

Needed case:

1. Click on "Clone this row"
2. Type anything in the cloned input
3. The value of first input **has not changed**
4. The value of cloned input has changed

Here is the **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pBvCTSpcw2gexq2BAkxW?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `angular.copy()` which creates a **deep copy** or clone of actual object reference:

```
$scope.comments.push(angular.copy(comment));
```

[updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YfbzjlLW7XlFPqo4cEAX?p=preview)

---

`angular.copy()` creates a clone of the original object and updates a copy not the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you have references on your objects, you have to copy, and not to reference your object.

Use `angular.copy()` to copy your object attr values in a new object instead of copying this reference